# how to use includes method on Array that is input property to the component in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an input property on the component like this

```
  @Input() testArray? = [];
```

And I have to apply disable on the items that are present in this array something like this

```
<mat-option 
    *ngFor="let item of selectionList" 
    [value]="item" 
    [disabled]="testArray.includes(item.text)" >
     
    {{item.text}}

</mat-option>
```

But I am getting below mentioned error:-

> Object is possibly 'undefined'.ngtsc(2532) select.component.ts(13,
> 32): Error occurs in the template of component SelectComponent.

How to solve this situation

Comment: have you tried using an Angular Pipe for this?